# Create ActiveXObject from GUID

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, com, activex, activexobject

I have the following line in my code:

```
var ScreenRecorder = new ActiveXObject('CCScreenRecorder.ScreenRecorder');
```

The problem is that I have 2 entries of this
(one for each version, don't ask me why - this is a fact I need to deal with),

So I want to create the `ActiveXObject` from the GUID.

I tried to do:

```
document.createElement('<OBJ' + 'ECT ID="ScreenRecorderWrapper" CLA' + 'SSID="CL' + 'SID:37CCF998-3BB7-' + '4F8A-9D9F-EF391543E94A"></OB' + 'JECT>');
var ScreenRecorder = ScreenRecorderWrapper;
```

but the problem is that `ScreenRecorderWrapper` will be defined only after `SetTimeout` or some other manipulation.

Can I get the `ActiveXObject` from it's GUID and not from it's name?
Something like:

```
var ScreenRecorder = new ActiveXObject('37CCF668-3BB7-4F8A-9D9F-EF391543E94A');
```

Answer (score 0):

`ActiveXObject` requires a ProgID, however, you can use a version-dependent ProgID rather than a version-independent ProgID.

Version-dependent ProgIDs typically have a version number appended to the version-independent ProgID.

In this case, the version-independent ProgID is `'CCScreenRecorder.ScreenRecorder'`, and the version-dependent ProgID would be something like `'CCScreenRecorder.ScreenRecorder.1'` or `'CCScreenRecorder.ScreenRecorder.2'`.

Note that using a version-dependent ProgID can fail if the wrong version is installed.  You might want to try the version-dependent ProgID first, and fall back to the version-independent ProgID.

Comment: The progid is the same for both of them, both of them is CCScreenRecorder.ScreenRecorder, I can't see version difference.

Comment: @DorCohen That's the [*version independent*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms694514(v=vs.85).aspx) progid.  The [version dependent](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd542719(v=vs.85).aspx) key is stored separately in the registry, and should have a different name for the different CLSIDs.  (If the version dependent progids are identical, you're kinda hosed.)

Answer (score 0):

Use the registry for obtaining the ProgId from the CLSID.
Reading the registry in JS is possible through the "Shell" ActiveX

```
var shellObj = new ActiveXObject("WScript.Shell");
var clsid = "37CCF668-3BB7-4F8A-9D9F-EF391543E94A";
var progid = shellObj.RegRead("HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\\CLSID\\{"+clsid+"}\\ProgID\\");
var ScreenRecorder = new ActiveXObject( progid );
```

Comment: Please add some explanation.

Comment: Your solution didn't help me since both GUID's returns me the same progid.

Comment: Sorry for that. You can't use CLSID in ActiveXObject. Only solution is the one with the <OBJECT> tag. What's your problem with this one?